# Map sorted on size of value collection

Tags: java, dictionary, java-7, treemap, sortedmap

I'm trying to have a sorted map `Map<Integer,Set<Integer>>` which keeps elements sorted based on the `size()` of the value set.

In practice this is a map of a node to the other nodes connected to that node. I want to quickly (O(logn)) access the node with the most edges **without having to sort** every time.

For example the order should be:

```
3 => {1,2,4,5}
12 => {1,2,3}
14 => {3,2,3}
65 => {3,8}
6 => {2}
2 => {5}
```

Since `TreeMap` won't do it since I can't sort based on values, I probably need to roll something custom.

**EDIT:** The size of the Set may indeed change which may over-complicate things even more

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean `TreeMap` won't do?  You can use a custom Comparator.

Comment: @markspace The comparator only allows me to sort by key (unless I want to adopt another ugly/unreliable hack/solution)

Comment: Reverse the key and the value.  You said you want to look up by size right?

Comment: I need both a `get(on the node id)` and `highest()` to return the node with the most edges

Comment: So use two maps.  One sorted by Set#size, and one index by node ID.  It's the easiest way.

Comment: @markspace how would he `get` from the one sorted by size?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Since he wants the largest Set size, I'd say TreeMap#lastEntry().

Comment: Plz define if the size of each Set may change after insertion; you have a mutable key here(size) and it needs proper handling.

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias Yes, it may indeed change and possibly complicates things even more now that I think about it

Comment: A fast solution is that you never use get() when updating; but always remove, do your changes, then store it back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sort example how to use two sets for this.  One set is sorted by Set::size, and the other is just a normal Map with an integer index.  To use this, you have to keep the same key/value pairs in both maps.

I'm not sure if I'd recommend trying to make a single Map out of this.  It's got two lookups, by index and by size, so it doesn't really work like a regular map.  It will depend on your use model.

```
package quicktest;

import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TreeMapTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TreeMap<Integer,Set<Integer>> index = new TreeMap<>();
      TreeMap<Set<Integer>,Integer> size = new TreeMap<>( comparing( Set::size ) );

      for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { 
         Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
         for( int val = 0; val <= i; val++ ) {
            set.add( val );
         }
         index.put( i, set );
         size.put( set, i );
      }
      System.out.println( size.lastEntry() ); // largest set size
      System.out.println( index.get( 2 ) );  // random index
   }
}
```

Comment: This would only work if we don't change a Set.size after being inserted, because sorting key (the size) is mutable. You need proper control when adding/removing elements from each Set.

Comment: Or make a copy of the Sets before you insert them, so that later changes don't affect the Sets already stored.  I'd be inclined to go this route.

Comment: But OP wants to update indexMap after insertion; so get, change (add/remove elements) then store back

Comment: Which is basically what I said.  You mean the get/change/put cycle isn't desired?  I don't see a way around it.  If you try to add "control" to a HashSet, you change an O(1) algorithm to O(log n) where n is the total number of sets stored in the system.  That seems bad, and inflexible.

Comment: No I say it is desired (I explain what it needs to be done). I don't understand though how a clone before insertion can help

Comment: If you make a deep copy, then any changes made to the original Set are not reflected in the copy in the TreeSet.  Thus, no special controls on the original set are needed.

Comment: I know what a deep copy is. But it seems OP has a Map, where it requires constant updates. When an update is required, he may retrieve the Key/Value pair, perform changes, then store it back. So, how a deep copy would work here?. I guess the solution is that you have to remove previous key/value pair (Integer,Set), alter it, then add it back.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
public class MapAndPriority {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> sets = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>();
    PriorityQueue<Set<Integer>> byLength = new PriorityQueue<Set<Integer>>(1, new Comparator<Set<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Set<Integer> o1, Set<Integer> o2) {
            // Compare in the reverse order!
            return o2.size() - o1.size();
        }
    });

    public void add(int i, Set<Integer> set) {
        sets.put(i, set);
        byLength.offer(set); // or Add, depending on the behavior you want
    }

    public Set<Integer> get(int i) {
        return sets.get(i);
    }

    public Set<Integer> mostNodes() {
        return byLength.peek();
    }

    public void remove(int i) {
        // sets.remove will return the removed set, so that will be removed from byLength. 
        // Need to handle case when i does not exist as a key in sets
        byLength.remove(sets.remove(i));

    }
}
```

If I understand what you want, then this will:

1. Add new sets in o(nlog(n))
2. Regular map `get()`
3. Will get the largest set (`mostNodes()`) in o(log(n))

What I did was to place all sets in a priority queue (along side the map) and then give the priority queue a comparator that compares based on the sizes, so that smaller size  is "larger". That way when you call `peek()` it will return the 'minimum' value in the priority queue, which due to our comparator it will be the longest set.
I didn't deal with all kinds of edge cases (like removing when empty).

You can take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for more details and about the complexity.

Comment: Found a small bug  in my implementation. If you change the sets after insertion, then calling `mostNodes` won't work. If you want to be able to change sets after insertion, you can add another method to `MapAndPriority` which adds/removes elements from a set. It will then need to remove the set from the priority queue, change it, and then re-add it.

Comment: Your fix suggestion would work only if you are sure that no-one else have access to any of the Sets and change their size without calling you suggested add/remove method. I guess an Observer pattern would provide a more proper solution to this issue.

Comment: Well, without knowing the bigger picture I cannot defend my suggestion. But in general, you can expose only this class, and have the getters return read only copies.